# Angular ViewChild is undefined - why?

Tags: angular, runtime-error, undefined, viewchild

I tried to implement (to test my skills) my own toast message service - dynamically add my toast message to the page. I developed a toast message service - which (I think) is not important here (nothing special inside). Also, I added a single ToastMessage component, which I didn't include here because I think also not important here. So, first I added a directive:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[toastMessagesPlaceholder]' })
export class PlaceholderDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}
```

Then a component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-toast-messages',
  templateUrl: './toast-messages.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toast-messages.component.css'],
})
export class ToastMessagesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  toastSubscribe: Subscription;
  @ViewChild(PlaceholderDirective) set toastPlaceholder(pd: PlaceholderDirective) {
    console.log("placeholder is set", pd);
  }

  constructor(private messagingService: MessagingService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.toastSubscribe = this.messagingService.toastList.subscribe(
      (msg: ToastMessage) => this.showToast(msg)
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.toastSubscribe.unsubscribe();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit here", this.toastPlaceholder);
  }

  showToast(msg: ToastMessage) {
    const hostViewContainerRef = this.toastPlaceholder.viewContainerRef;

    const componentRef = hostViewContainerRef.createComponent(ToastComponent);
    componentRef.instance.prepare(msg);
  }
}
```

Where the `html` is:

```
<div class="toast-placeholder">
    <ng-template toastMessagesPlaceholder></ng-template>    
</div>
```

I added it to the layout (app.component) html directly:

```
<app-toast-messages></app-toast-messages>
<div class="container-fluid">
   ..
</div>
```

I was able to active its `showToast(..)` method, but on the very first line I got an error on console:

> placeholder is set undefined

> ngAfterViewInit here undefined

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'viewContainerRef')
> at ToastMessagesComponent.showToast (toasts-messages.component.ts:82:56)
> at Object.next (toasts-messages.component.ts:68:35)

I debugged the code, and found that in `showToast(..)` first line of code the `this.toastPlaceholder` is undefined. I added some console logging which you can see above.

I had no idea what is the problem. When I inspect the html the required elements are there:

```
<body>
  <app-root _nghost-yvi-c61="" ng-version="15.2.0">
     <app-toast-messages _ngcontent-yvi-c61="" _nghost-yvi-c60="">
          <div _ngcontent-yvi-c60="" class="toast-placeholder"><!--container--></div>
     </app-toast-messages>
     <div _ngcontent-yvi-c61="" class="container-fluid">
```

What I found about a `@ViewChild` is undefined usually talks about some problems with `*ngIf` - which I didn't use. So - I am puzzled. Any idea of an expert? Please ... Thanks!

Comment: Try `{ static: true }` in the `ViewChild` declaration.

Comment: Tried. All remains the same. :( undefined, undefined, error.

Comment: I wonder how ViewChild works, what's behind the scene. Is it a kind of magic?

Comment: I started a SandBox project. It seems `ViewChild` works with local references well, but with `Directive` - wont. Is it true - I wonder ...

Answer (score 1):

Today, I had some more time for this problem.

First, let's define our `ToastComponent` like this:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'toast-component',
  template: `
    <div style="width: 300px; border: 1px solid black; display: flex; align-items: center;justify-content: space-between;">
      <p>{{toastMessage}} {{toastId}}</p>
      <button (click)=close()>close</button>
    </div>
  `,
  standalone: true,
})
export class ToastComponent implements OnInit {
  toastMessage = 'default toast message';
  toastId: number;

  constructor(private host: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  close() {
    this.host.nativeElement.remove();
  }
}
```

This is a really simple component with an adjustable message and a self destructing close event.

After that let's define our directive:

```
import {
  ComponentRef,
  Directive,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  ViewContainerRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { ToastComponent } from './toast.component';

@Directive({
  selector: '[toast]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class ToastDirective implements OnInit {
  _hideAfter: number;
  @Input('toast') messageComp: ComponentRef<ToastComponent> | null = null;
  @Input('toastHideAfter') set hideAfter(value: number) {
    this._hideAfter = value;
  }

  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.messageComp) {
      this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(ToastComponent);
    }
  }
}
```

Our default input to the directive is a `ComponentRef` of type `ToastComponent`. I have added another input too, if hiding the toast after some seconds is needed. In the `ngOnInit` method we add the `ToastComponent` to the `ViewContainerRef` if the input is set.

After that let's define our test component.

html:

```
<button (click)="showToast()">show toast</button>
<div *toast="messageFromExternalComp; hideAfter: 3000"></div>
```

ts:

```
import {
  Component,
  ComponentRef,
  OnInit,
  ViewContainerRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { ToastComponent } from './toast.component';
import { ToastDirective } from './toast.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'comp-with-toast',
  templateUrl: './comp-with-toast.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ToastDirective, ToastComponent],
})
export class CompWithToastComponent implements OnInit {
  messageFromExternalComp: ComponentRef<ToastComponent>;
  toastId = 0;

  constructor(private vcr: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  showToast() {
    const toastComponentRef = this.vcr.createComponent(ToastComponent);
    toastComponentRef.instance.toastMessage = 'your custom message';
    toastComponentRef.instance.toastId = this.toastId++;
    this.messageFromExternalComp = toastComponentRef;
  }
}
```

In the `showToast` event we create a reference to our `ToastComponent`, set the properties and assign it to the input property of the directive.

Here is a working stackblitz (with standalone components):

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdabgo)

ps: greetings from Hungary

Comment: Thank you for your kind time. I was able to solve the problem also, and as I see you choose a "workaround" . Which indeed good. But my question still "is it correct to use ViewChild with a directive? @ViewChild(PlaceholderDirective)?"